# Windows regedit is overwriting my changes

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, regedit

I have an app written in C# using WPF. I want to start the app on windows startup, minimized, so I have this piece of code:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue("MyApp", "\""+path+"\" /minimized");
```

It writes correctly to the regedit

```
"C:\path\myapp.exe" /minimized
```

But when I restart the computer, it overwrites to

```
C:\path\myapp.exe
```

And opens the app maximized

I also tried /background

Any ideas why this behavior?

Comment: More info needed.  Where is your "piece of code" running which sets the reg value in the first place?

Comment: It's the action of a checkbox click

Comment: Well, anything could be going on here.  It's hard to know because we don't have access to your system.  This question, as it currently exists, is un-answerable.

Comment: Are you sure this is the only place where your application writes this value to the registry?

Comment: Does your app start with Window? If so you can make the WindowState Minimised from the properties of the window?

Comment: @αNerd My app needs to start minimized on startup. But if the app is closed and he opens manually, it must open maximized.